# How to invalidate data without triggering isFetching in React-Query?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I'm using React Query to fetch data for my table:

```
const { data: invoice, isFetching, isLoading, refetch } = useQuery(['invoice', taxpayer, page, filtered, state], ()=>index(taxpayer, page, filtered, state), {
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    keepPreviousData: true,
    cacheTime: 3000,
    retry: false, 
    select: (response: any) =>response.data,
    onSuccess: () => setStateLoading(false)}
)
```

What I need to do is to refetch data without triggering `isFetching` function, and why is that, because I want my users not to notice fetching icon on my table:

```
if (isFetching || isLoading) {
    return <div className={classes.loading}>
        <Skeleton/>
    </div>
}
```

I'm doing this because I have to send timely requests for fetching new data and I don't want users to notice loading icon, that's a table with every time updated data.

Answer (score 2):

> What I need to do is to refetch data without triggering isFetching

That's no how it works. `isFetching` will be true every time a request is in-flight, no matter if it's the first request or a background refetch.

> because I want my users not to notice fetching icon on my table:

if you don't want that, then don't render the skeleton based on this condition.

- if you want to check for the first request where you have no data, use `isLoading`
- if you want to check for all refetches, use `isRefetching`
- if you want to check for all requests, use `isFetching`

Comment: thanks, isn't there any mechanism to kind of silent update everything without having isFetching or isRefetching triggered? I don't want to lose isLoading or isFetching at the same time I need to update some portion of my data without triggering them. @tkdodo

Comment: you can write data into the cache with `queryClient.setQueryData`. But if a fetch happens, those flags will be set. You can always ignore them if you want, so I'm struggling to understand your use-case...